# Link in Experience cloud to navigate to another page errors out

Tags: community, customer-community, lightning-community, community-builder, experience-cloud

I'm using a Customer Account Portal template for my Experience Cloud and I am having issues trying to add a link in the HTML Editor from the Home page to another page, Request Access.  Request Access page is published and in the HTML Editor I did the following scenarios,

```
1. <a href="/requestaccess">click</a>
2. <a href="/s/requestaccess">click</a>
3. <a href="{thewholeURL including domain}/requestaccess">click</a>
4. <a href="{thewholeURL including domain}/s/requestaccess">click</a>
```

I've tried using other pages that were already created but to no avail.  However, when I copy and paste the whole url like in step 4 I to the url browser I get the page.  Please help.

Comment: I assume `<a> href...` is a typo in the question and you meant `<a href...`? I also assume the missing end quotes for the href is also a typo in the question...?

Comment: Yes it is @PhilW. I will update

Comment: I was able to figure this out. In the HTML editor from the home page of my community, I used the following <a href="../s/requestaccess">click</a>

Comment: It would be good to know - did you have a URL path for the digital experience? You would need that in your host relative URL. Alternatively, you could try a page relative URL like `requestaccess` instead... Great it is working for you.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, [Seng Soukhavong](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/110529/seng-soukhavong)!!

There seems to have been a change in the Spring '24 release, so that links that were fine previously now either duplicated the community's specific path if included, as they were previously:

- ***path:** <a href="/CommunityName/s/PageName"*
- ***outcome:** MyDomain.sandbox.my.site.com/CommunityName/s/CommunityName/s/PageName*

or left it out altogether if I removed it:

- ***path:** <a href="/s/PageName"*
- ***outcome:** MyDomain.sandbox.my.site.com/s/CommunityName/s/PageName*

Adding the dots before the /s/ has fixed it.

- ***path:** <a href="../s/PageName"*
- ***outcome:** MyDomain.sandbox.my.site.com/CommunityName/s/PageName*

Comment: this appears to work on all my pages but my login page, I have an html link in an html editor and if I use the ../s/pagename it appends /s/login/pagename which the page does not exist so if a user click its they get invalid page.